# mongoDB mongoimport upsert

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I'm trying to do a bulk update with the following

```
mongoimport -d my_db -c db_collection -upsertFields email ~/Desktop/update_list.csv
```

the csv that i'm trying to import looks like this.

```
email, full_name
stack@overflow.com,stackoverflow
mongo@db.com,mongodb
```

It should check the email column as a query arg and update the full name accordingly. However, none were imported, it encountered errors.

```
exception:Failure parsing JSON string near: abc@sa
abc@sasa.com,abc
imported 0 objects
encountered 99398 errors
```

Where is the problem? How should i be doing it?

Answer (score 16):

Your mongoimport command is missing the --upsert option, which is needed in combination with --upsertFields. Try:

```
mongoimport -d my_db -c db_collection --upsert --upsertFields email ~/Desktop/update_list.csv
```

Comment: as of  version 3.0.0: --upsertFields now implies --upsert. As such, you may prefer to use --upsertFields instead of --upsert.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsert

Answer (score 6):

Add --type csv

Otherwise it assumes your input is json.

Also, looks like you should pass --headerline to make it use the first line of the file as a header.

Comment: i added both args --type csv and --headerline, all were imported, but not updated. I end up having duplicates.

Comment: Mongoimport cannot update existing records... It only inserts new records. You could try dropping the existing collection before running the import (which you can do with the --drop flag to mongo import). See full documentation here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Comment: Well, actually it can. You just need to add the --upsert option (as suggested by Andy Triggs)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the data inside your CSV file must be double-quoted.

Comment: I resaved my csv so my data are all double-quoted. I managed to get all of it imported, but they were not updated. I end up having duplicates.