# MongoDB update multiple rows at a time

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of 1000 documents already having column `old_col`.

Now I want to add new columns in this existing document, for multiple rows at once.

For instance, the existing situation would be:

```
{"old_col"=1},{"old_col"=2},{"old_col"=1000}
```

...to be changed to:

```
{"old_col"=1,"new_col"=11},{"old_col"=2,"new_col"=12},{"old_col"=1000,"new_col"=11000}.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a calculation to arrive at `new_col`? If not, where are the values from?

Comment: We are not calculating column, but lets say i already have data for new_col mapped to old_col, now we are trying to insert new column new_col for each old_col.

Comment: Just do it one by one, it is just 1000 documents. If you need to rollback in the middle, you can remove the partially completed `new_col` again.

Comment: Thanks! but in future we may need to do the same for huge data, so i wanted to do it once for all documents to avoid updating one by one.

Comment: The `mongoimport` command line tool can do upserts, that should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915007/14955